# Flow Promise This type is incompatible with undefined undefined

Tags: react-native, flowtype, exponent, expo

Get warning [image]

on line:

[image]

Use Flow.js v.0.48.0.
Code sample:

```
...
import { Font, AppLoading } from 'expo';
...
export default class App extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync(fontsStore);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Found hack solution:

```js
...
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadFonts();
  }

  async loadFonts () {
    await Font.loadAsync(fontsStore);

    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }
...
```